# Linking VC 2012 command line failing

Tags: visual-c++, dll, linker, glfw

I just got the VC 2012 command line setup working but I ran into a problem linking the GLFW library. I copied and pasted the headers in my source folder and placed the library (DLL and OBJ files) in the exe's destination and the directory of the command line.

Here is what I do to compile:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link" "%CD%\glfw3.obj"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\cl" /EHsc %CD%\src\main.cpp
```

*glfw3.obj* is the obj file (there is one more, it's called *glfw3dll.objm*, I copied and pated it but I don't think it needs to be linked). There is also *glfw.dll*.

I get the error *LINK : fatel error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'glfw3.obj'*. And then when I call a GLFW function I get: *main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ referenced in function _main*.

If you have any questions about the problem post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to link the GLFW library is you already have a dll. The obj files are generated by the compiler, and linked together by the linker.

Try just calling `cl` on your main function.

Comment: Try compiling then linking